# while loop in a for php

Tags: php, loops, calendar, for-loop, while-loop

Building a calendar with events. I have built the calendar and now trying to add the events to the corresponding date.

```
$dayName = "Monday"; 
$mo = date($m);

  for($day = 1; $day <=7; $day++) 
  { 
    $timestamp = mktime(1,1,1,$mo,$day,$yr); 
    if(date('l', $timestamp) == $dayName) 
    { 


if(date('d', $timestamp) == 1){
    $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $m, $yr);

    for($date = 1; $date <=$num; $date++){
        if ($date == 1){
        print "<tr>";
        }
        print "<td";if($mo == date("m")){ if($date == date("d")){ if($yr == date("y")){ print " style=\"background:#97d2fd;\"";}}}print " onClick=\"location.href = '?v=dd&id=$m&y=$yr&mid=$mm&my=$myr&d=$date';\" height=\"80\">". $date."<br/>";

            $wqry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events")or die(mysql_error());

            if (mysql_num_rows($wqry) > 0){
                //need to be a while loop
                $wrow = mysql_fetch_array($wqry, MYSQL_ASSOC)  or die(mysql_error());
                $alldate = $date."/".$mo."/".$yr;

                if($alldate == $wrow['sdate']){


                    if($wrow['type'] == "1"){
                        print"<div id=\"hight\">";
                    }print $wrow['title']."</div><br/>";

                }

            }


        print"</td> ";
        if ($date == 7){
        print "</tr><tr>";
        }
        if ($date == 14){
        print "</tr><tr>";
        }
        if ($date == 21){
        print "</tr><tr>";
        }
        if ($date == 28){
        print "</tr>";
        }


    }

}

  break; 
  print"
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

</div>


</div>


    ";
        } 

      }
```

Trying to make it so that the events are shown in the right table. So far this code shows just one event. Im guessing the problem is putting a while loop in a for. As when I do:

> if (mysql_num_rows($wqry) > 0){
>
> ```
>               while($wrow = mysql_fetch_array($wqry, MYSQL_ASSOC)  or
> ```
>
> die(mysql_error())){
>                     $alldate = $date."/".$mo."/".$yr;
>
> ```
>               if($alldate == $wrow['sdate']){
>
>
>                   if($wrow['type'] == "1"){
>                       print"<div id=\"hight\">";
>                   }print $wrow['title']."</div><br/>";
>
>               }
>
>           }
>           }
> ```

It just shows the first date of the month. Meaning that it must stop the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

It's because its just returning the first row from your database each time as its looping for each day in the month, you need to replace the query with something like:

```
$wqry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE sdate='$alldate'")
```